# kafka-python Error when i havent received message since a long period

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I use the kafka_python==2.0.0 library ,

With the piece of code below, if I do not receive a message for 1 hour, the next message pushed in the kafka topic are not processed by the consumer, however the loop does not stop.

I would like my listener to run 24/24 without losing the connection

```
 consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    os.environ.get('MY_TOPIC'),
    bootstrap_servers=broker,
    api_version=my_version,
    security_protocol='SASL_PLAINTEXT',
    sasl_mechanism='GSSAPI',
    sasl_kerberos_service_name=service_name,
    group_id='MY_GRP_ID',
    max_poll_records=1
    
)

try:
    for msg in consumer:
        ##PROCESS function ... 
        consumer.commit()
       
finally:
    consumer.close()
```

Comment: I have no log or error , the loop is just waiting indefinitly the next iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use the poll method :

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

# To consume latest messages and auto-commit offsets
consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic',
                         group_id='my-group',
                         bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
while True:
    # Response format is {TopicPartiton('topic1', 1): [msg1, msg2]}
    msg_pack = consumer.poll(timeout_ms=500)

    for tp, messages in msg_pack.items():
        # message value and key are raw bytes -- decode if necessary!
        # e.g., for unicode: `message.value.decode('utf-8')`
        print ("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (tp.topic, tp.partition,
                                              message.offset, message.key,
                                              message.value))
```

The advantage of my point to this syntax is better visibility on how to retrieve messages. it is not in my example but I could better manage the stopping of the program by loking for a sigterm signal